# Are Vikipedio articles written using good Esperanto?

Tags: culture

The English Wikipedia doesn't have a great reputation, especially among educators. I would like to read articles in Esperanto as a way to improve my vocabulary and expose myself to well written Esperanto. Does the Esperanto Wikipedia contain well-written articles?

Comment: I can't say anything bad about the grammar, but the content of the Intersex article was appalling.

Comment: FWIW, I have written 16 articles in Esperanto, which you can access here: http://www.public-domain-materials.com/dosierujo-artikoloj-en-esperanto.html

Comment: @CharlotteSL Agreed. But why not write a new one? I'm afraid I can't be of help at my level of Esperanto yet, though.

Comment: @LaVo Yeah, I've been meaning to, but I'm procrastinating.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. The Esperanto Wikipedia does contain well-written articles, but that does not mean all articles are well written. According to my experience, language quality in the Esperanto Wikipedia is mostly quite OK, but not perfect. For improving your language skills, it is mostly usable.

Answer (score 10):

You can find a list of featured/good Wikipedia Esperanto articles down here

- [Featured articles](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikipedio:Elstaraj_artikoloj) (Elstaraj artikoloj)
- [Good articles](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikipedio:Legindaj_artikoloj) (Legindaj artikoloj)